# Algorithms for rooted directed acyclic graph isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, isomorphism-testing, directed-graphs

Given two directed acyclic graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$, and their roots $r_1$ and $r_2$, is there a polynomial algorithm to determine if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic?

Comment: Wikipedia says this problem is GI-complete, that is, that GI problems can be reduced to DAGI problems in polynomial time.

Comment: Link for reference in the comment by @user44191 : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem#GI-complete_classes_of_graphs And, to spell it out: if rooted DAG isomorphism was a polynomial-time problem, then Graph Isomorphism would be in P, and we would have solved a famous open problem: Graph Isomorphism _...is not known to be solvable in polynomial time nor to be NP-complete, and therefore may be in the computational complexity class NP-intermediate._

Comment: Thanks a lot! so what's the best algorithm so far, if I assign each node a label, is the problem becomes simpler?